# docker-compose error connection ECONNREFUSED

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a web service that is packed inside Docker image. I use compose to build this image and run it. I use docker desktop to run docker containers.

So, to run service I just need to type:
`docker-compose run app`

compose file:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      target: app
    ports
      - 5001:5001
```

docker file:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim as app
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY entrypoint.sh .
CMD ["sh", "/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

However, I face following issue: when I try to get this service GET http://localhost:5001/up I get **Error: connect ECONNREFUSED**

I can't figure out why I can't access service. Any help/comment/explanation will be mush appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing what's running inside the image, it's hard to say.  Is the application code listening on `0.0.0.0:5001` (not listening on `127.0.0.1` and not listening on some other port)?  Is the `entrypoint.sh` script actually launching the server?

Comment: wsgi server (application server) runs python web service on 5001 port

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the docker is running using the command `docker ps` ?

If it's running, please check if the port is listening using `netstat -tnulp | grep 5001`

Also check if firewall is blocking the connection

Comment: looks like I nothing is listening 5001 port

Comment: Then either the docker is not listening on the port or the docker is not running at all